# How to use the Raw_Input/User Input to replace certain lines of Text in a Text File

Tags: python-2.7, replace, user-input

Currently I have a text File labelled *Test1.txt*, where there are lines of Text written like so:

```
 Question 2) Delete This
 a) Sample Text
 b) Sample Text
```

I would like to replace the 'Delete This' segment of the seventh line with a User Input.

Note; The line of text: [*Question 2) Delete This*] ,is the seventh line.

How would someone replace a certain part of a line of text, by using the raw_input? 
This is the code so far

```
    f = open('Test1.txt', 'r+')
    f.write(raw_input("Start Writing:\n"))
    f.close()
```

This successfully writes the User Input onto the file Test1.txt. Yet it obviously just writes it onto the first line.
 I am not sure how to replace the 'Delete This' with the User Input.

I would like to know how to replace a section of a line with the User Input.

For example if the User Enters: abc

Then the text file would read:

```
Question 2) abc #rather than Delete This
a) Sample Text
b) Sample Text
```

Very New to Python, so any explanation on any code would be Much Appreciated!
Thanks

Potential Duplicate: [Writing multiple lines to a textfile by taking input in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27330316/writing-multiple-lines-to-a-textfile-by-taking-input-in-python)

Comment: You want to change the text while printing it on screen right and you want tom change only delete this to the text the user has given to you right